# Calling a function from a string

Tags: python-2.7

I have the following code

```
str = "Hello , World"

FunctionToCall = str.split(",")[0]

def Hello():
    print "succes"
```

How do I get something like this to work? I've tried:

```
FunctionToCall = str.split(",")[0]()
```

but this returns the following error:

```
TypeError: 'str' object is not callable
```

Comment: do you actually want to call the `Hello` function based on the value of the string?

Comment: don't use a variable named "str" since that shadows a [built in function](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#str). (But in fact it should still work...)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OK, I'm assuming that you're actually trying to do the following:

1. Parse the string 'Hello , world' and get the first entry, 'Hello'
2. Based on this, call the function named `Hello`.

First, you shouldn't use "str" as the variable name, since it shadows a [built-in function](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#str). (Your version would have actually worked in your case, but it's a bad idea).

```
 strng = "Hello , world"     #note new name
```

Second, you could parse your string a little better: it currently has a space after "Hello". You can do this by using [`string.strip`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/string.html#string.strip). (Again, your version would work for most cases, but the extra `strip` is a little cleaner.)

```
 functionToCall = strng.split(",")[0].strip()
```

But most importantly, you need to call the function based on the given name. There are a number of ways to do this, with various degrees of safety. The easiest is to use the [`eval`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#eval) function:

```
 eval(functionToCall)()
```

[You could also use `eval(functionToCall + '()')`.]

But `eval` is generally considered dangerous, since it can execute arbitrary code. Here, you can instead take advantage of the fact that your `Hello` function is defined in the global namespace, and so has an entry in the [`globals()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#globals) dictionary. which is the actual function you care about:

```
  globals()[functionToCall]()
```

Comment: the eval thing works, and since I'm only using the script for myself, I'm not so worried about this security, or should I be?

Answer (score -1):

Since I got downvoted, I probably didn't quite understand what the OP wanted to do. So I came up with a completely new answer.

#### New answer

If you want to call a function that has the same name as a string you got from somewhere, you could try doing the following:

```
def Hello():
    print "Success!"

def default():
    print "No such function!"

# create a dictionary with the names and corresponding functions
d = {"Hello": Hello}

s = "Hello , World!"

# check if the string you extract with s.split() is a function by
# looking in the dictionary; this will print "Success" if "Hello"
# is in the dictionary and "No such function" if it's not
FunctionToCall = d.get(s.split(",")[0].strip(), default)()

# output: Success!
```

This method should be safer than using `eval()` to evaluate a string.

Comment: I actually got my string from a dictionary:
dict = {1 : "Hello, World"}
can I use this dictionary? or should I create a second dict in order to call the function?

Comment: btw, I did not downvote your first attempt, so Idk about that

Comment: @zazga I would create a second dictionary to keep things readable, since the string that is the value of the first dictionary still needs to be operated on ("Hello, World" needs to become "Hello" first).

Comment: @zazga but really, if you want an answer how to best solve a problem, you should post about what you really want to achieve, instead of trying to get some rather strange methods to work for you. This may be a classic [XY Problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem)